# Count the number of lines between the first and last lines and compare that count to another value

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a text file like

> 0000062015    <----line one
>   A EEE
>   A EEE
>   A EEE
>   C EEE
>   C EEE
>   A EEE
>   END           <-----final line

1. The script is to read the 1st line and get first 6 digits
2. Then counting number of lines from line 2 until the line before END (there should be 6 lines because the first six digits of the first line form the number 000006), then compare whether these two numbers are the same.

I know that I can use

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" 20150629_eleave_i_test.txt | find /C ":""

for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
echo %number%
```

to count all lines in this file, but I don't know to extract the substring that I want from the first line, or how to compare the two numbers.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Code modified as requested in a comment*

```
@echo off
setlocal

set filename=textFile.txt

rem Read number of lines from first line in file
set /p number=< "%filename%"
set /A number=1%number:~0,6% - 1000000

rem Get the number of lines-2 and the last line via findstr /N
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%filename%"') do (
   set /A count=%%a-2
   set "lastLine=%%b"
)

if "%lastLine%" neq "END" (
   echo The last line is not "END"
)

if %number% equ %count% (
   echo Numbers are the same
) else (
   echo Different numbers
)
```

Comment: Aacini, your ans is great. Regarding to  
set /A number=1%number:~0,6% - 1000000
i want to clarify some minor probems

0,6%<-- I already know it means getting 6 character starting from position 0.

But what does "1" there means and why 1000000 is subtracted?I dont really get them.Thanks

Comment: In `set /A` command, the numbers that start with zero are taken as _octal numbers_ (in the same way than numbers that start with 0x are taken as hexadecimal; type: `set /?`), so `set /A number=000008` for example would issue an error because `8` is _not_ a valid octal digit, and `set /A number=000010` set a decimal `8` (_not_ ten) to number. We need to eliminate leading zeros, and a very simple way to do that is inserting a "1" digit before the string of six digits, and then subtract its value: `set /A number=1000008 - 1000000 = 8`

Comment: Dear Aacini, i miss one requirement.
I have to check whether the string on the last line is END.I searched and tried but i only find 
for /f "delims==" %%a in (20150629_eleave_i_test.txt) do set lastline=%%a
echo %lastline%
It really give me "END", but what is the syntax  to use  if  to compare with "END" then echo some text
Thanks

Comment: Please, try to state all specifications in the original question. It is not a good idea to request _new_ modifications to terminated code... See the edit in my answer.

Comment: Hi Aacini, in the text file ,when i press "Enter" at the final line to create 3 new next lines, the %%a would count those blank lines also and the %lastLine% will be storing blank char, it causes error message even the format of the text is right, any helps or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

:: If your text file isn't in the same directory as your script, you need
:: to add the full path to the file instead.
set "text_file=20150629_eleave_i_test.txt"

:: Get the first six characters of the first line of the text file
set /p first_six=<%text_file%
set first_six=!first_six:~0,6!

:: Remove the leading zeroes
set /a first_six=1!first_six!-1000000

:: Count the number of lines in the text file, then subtract two
:: because we're not counting the first or last lines
set count=0
for /F %%A in (%text_file%) do set /a count+=1
set /a count=!count!-2

if !count! equ !first_six! (
    echo Values match
) else (
    echo Values do not match
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    Rem For each txt file in current folder
    for %%f in (*.txt) do (

        Rem Retrieve the first line and the number of lines in the file
        Rem and prepare the data for later compare
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in ('
            ^< "%%~ff" ( 
                set /p "nLines="
                ^& set nLines
                ^& find /c /v ""
            ^)
        ') do if "%%b"=="" (set /a "count=1000000+%%a-2") else (set "nLines=%%b")

        Rem Check if both values are equal or not
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for /f "tokens=1-2" %%a in ("1!nLines:~0,6! !count!") do (
            endlocal
            if "%%a" equ "%%b" ( 
                echo OK  - %%f
            ) else ( 
                echo BAD - %%f
            )
        )
    )
```